# How can I bind a variable to an unused AVR I/O register using avr-gcc?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

I would like to bind a global variable to an unused I/O register (e.g. PORTB) using avr-gcc, to reduce code size. I learned this trick in AVR's application note [AVR035](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1497.pdf) (page 14).

In the application note, they use the IAR compiler and bind the variable to an I/O register like this:

```
__no_init volatile uint8_t counter@0x35;
```

With avr-gcc, I can bind a variable to a standard register (r3 in this case) using this line:

```
register uint8_t counter asm("r3");
```

This does not work for I/O registers though. Is there a way to do this for I/O registers?

Comment: whoa, this is a nice trick. but one question: when you're thinking about the *code size* gains from using IN and OUT instead of STS and LDS, why aren't you coding the whole thing in assembly in the first place?

Comment: Assembly is probably a good idea on this level of code tweaking :-) I was hoping for a "quick" gain by just moving some global vars to i/o registers. Turned out it is not *that* easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this works for **global variables** only, what about just using something like this to use, for example the Uart Baud Rate Register:

```
#define myGlobalVariable UBRR
```

<strike>Also note that this optimization is only worth it if you're doing a lot of bit testing, because there are direct bit testing instructions for most of the IO registers.</strike> Oh, I forgot that not all AVRs have the LDS and STS instructions and some access SRAM only through the Z register, which makes a big difference in both code size and speed compared to a simple IN and OUT...

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now. However I noticed that using UBRR actually increased code size compared to a SRAM var. Using e.g. PORTB saved a couple of bytes though. Probably I need to look more closely what the compiler does here.

Comment: @henning77 IO registers are usually `volatile` which means that the compiler must generate IO operations for *every* read or write in the source code. With (non-volatile) variables the compiler can optimize accesses away by caching values in registers. Example: `i = 5; i = i + 1; i = i * 2;` requires 3 writes and 2 reads from the IO register aliased to `i` but only a single write to the global non-volatile variable `i`.